How do I validate email in PHPMailer which does not exists?
I want to know how to validate emails entered in the input box are real and exist, and if the provided email does not exist I want to throw an error.
What I mean to say is when I enter this email "test@gmail.com"(doesn't exist) and send it, I receive from mail delivery subsystem

but PHPMailer doesn't throw any error simply moves forward, do's what the next line in the program is.

[FYI] In the old days, you can use finger protocol to check whether an email exists (or not) -- but since it was extensively used by hackers (for social engineering attacks), by the late 1990s the vast majority of sites on the Internet no longer offered the service
